# Android educational games for small kids

Tags: android, game, educational

Please recommend me games for small kids (4-5 years)

Requirements

- Android platform
- Tablet optimized
- No Ads!
- No in-app payments!
- Educational
- Good for kids from 4 to 5 years
- Free or paid

Good examples:

- [Alphabet Cat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dreamcortex.alphabetCar)
- [Farm 123 ~ StoryToys Jr.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.storytoys.Farm123.GooglePlay)

Google play is full of crap apps, this is why I'm looking for recomendations

Comment: I suggest improving your questionm by adding a subject area, Eg Numeracy, Shape Recognition, Pattern Matching/Memory.
Otherwise the list is going to be too long

Comment: Alphabet Cat, Farm 123, Memory Game for kids. :-P.
Honestly I have no idea, otherwise I would be answering the question, I might be wrong. Maybe there are enough that this is a short list rather than a long one.
On rereading : The requirment for no ads actaully shortens this varstly more than any genre requirement.

Comment: @LyndonWhite 2 positions, not too long ;) It is not so easy to find application without ads ;)

Comment: Yeah, having restarted using a phone again lately, I am shocked at how hard it is to get apps without ads. Using a non-playstore FLOSS market place helps with that, but I think the biggest (F-Droid) has basically nothing for kids (not that I've looked)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[DragonBox](http://www.dragonboxapp.com/) helps children learn algebra using a very novel technique. It comes in 2 versions: a 5+ and a 12+ version.

I've only bought the 5+ version, not the 12+ version, so can't comment on the latter. But the 5+ version definitely helps you learn basic algebra concepts by pattern-matching, and I've found it to be a very cool concept. (You may not get far enough within the 15-minute trial window to get the concept, though, so be prepared to actually have to pay first.)

It's been a while since I've played the game (I stopped playing when I finished the game all the way through), so I don't know if the current version has ads or in-app purchases. But certainly, when I played it, it had neither of those antifeatures.

Answer (score 11):

I can propose following:

- [Memory Game For Kids](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.androidsoft.games.memory.kids) - an open source classic memorize game with nice looking tiles

I played this game on a 10" tablet with Android 4.1 and it looked very good (based on screenshots it is possible to run it also on mobile phones). This is an open source (GPL3+) project and the game is available for free, without adverts and no special permissions are needed. I have seen a two-year-old kid playing this game as well as an adult (me) training his memory. The tiles are adjusted to kids' perception and there are in game sounds which can attract the game even more.

Unfortunately the newest version was released over a year ago (December 2012), but game is fully functional although there could be more features added (like customizable board size).

- <strike>[Train Sim](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ogien.trainsim) - simple 3D train simulator</strike> (has adverts in online mode)

**Update**. More detailed information about Memory Game For Kids regarding to [the answer guide](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/youre-doing-it-all-wrong?cb=1).

Comment: Train Sim contains ads!

Comment: Really? I have never seem them. Maybe it is because I usually work in offline mode on my tablet.